# Show that E|Z| = 0

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let Z($\omega$) = {$0 \le t \le 1 $ |$W_t(\omega) = 0$} , the zero-set of the Brownian motion path up to 1 . Then Z is a Borel set and has the measure |Z| = $\int_{[0,1]}I_Z(t)dt$ , Show that E|Z| = 0.

My attempt is using $E|Z| =  \int_R \int I_Z(t)dtdP(\omega) $ , however , it seems this is not correct.

Comment: Got something from the answer below, after roughly one month?

Comment: I am still trying to understand how that integral equals $0$. $P(W_t=0)$ means $P(w|W_t(w)=0)$ , the set {$w|W_t(w)=0$} contains many points $w$.After that I can not make the connection how that integral can turn to 0. Are those  $w$ discrete ?

Comment: You have the distribution of $W_t$ at hand and you do not know what $P(W_t=0)$ is? Come...

Comment: Is it normal distribution ? I was taught it has normal increment so $W_t$ -$W_0$ = $W_t$ since $W_0$ = 0. So the probability at a particular value is 0 in continuous case.

Comment: Yes. (But try not to ask in public whether the distribution of $W_t$ is normal...)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Because I have very little confidence in my understanding, thus I want to ask.

Comment: So, all is clear now that you are sure that the distribution of $W_t$ is normal?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 5):

By Fubini, $\displaystyle E(|Z|)=\int_0^1\left(\int_\Omega\mathbf 1_{W_t=0}\,\mathrm dP\right)\mathrm dt=\int_0^1P(W_t=0)\,\mathrm dt=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it seems you skip some steps, can you please check if I understand correctly : E|Z| = $\int_{\Omega}ZdP(\omega) = \int_{\Omega} \int_{[0,1]}I_Z(t)dtdP(\omega)  $

then using Fubini,  $ \int_{[0,1]}\int_{\Omega}I_Z(t)dP(\omega)dt$ , and $\int_{\Omega}I_Z(t)dP(\omega) = P(W_t = 0)$ . Please correct me if I am wrong. and also how the integral on  [0,1] of P(Wt = 0) = 0 ?

Comment: You should really be able to answear your last question on your own if you're in any class talking about this..

Comment: Peter: I concur with @Kai's remark.